# Can I use mock to simulate a missing module in my unit tests?

Tags: python-2.7, mocking, python-unittest

My code is used on some systems that are missing certain python modules (eg. yaml, elasticsearch).

I want to write a unit test to make sure the code still runs if those modules aren't available.

Can I use mock to simulate an ImportError if any of those modules are imported?

I guess I'm imagining something like this might be possible:

```
import mock
import unittest

class TestMyTool(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.error_on_import(['yaml', 'elasticsearch'])
    def test(self):

        with self.assertRaises(ImportError):
            import yaml
        with self.assertRaises(ImportError):
            import elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 0):

have you considered the option of creating a "requirements.txt" listing all the dependencies and install those by "pip install -r requirements.txt" before executing your code?